# How to round down a decimal to integer

Tags: java, integer, decimal, rounding

So if I had the number 3.5, I want it to get the value 3.

```
for(i=0;i<25;i++){
int a = i/5;
}
```

I want it so int a takes the value of i/5, and rounds down. so if i is 6, int a = 6/5 (1.2) and becomes the value 1

Comment: by doing `i/5` and assigning that to an **integer** you are doing just this. in more detail: the division operator `/` for integers gives the whole number of the product. `3/2=1, 5/6=0, 2/1=2`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried your code? Dividing integer by another integer already works like what you've described, i.e. it will strip any decimal part, in turn "rounding it down". In your example code, `i/5` never becomes a "decimal" (which would be represented by `float` or `double`), unless you cast either value to `float`/`double` first and the store the result as the same type as what you've cast the value to.

Comment: @digeridoo it can be amazing what you can discover when you try the first code you can think of ;)